# How to create new ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile throw error back-off restarting failed container

Tags: docker

Dockerfile code

```
FROM mysql:5.6

COPY entrypoint_v1.sh /entrypoint_v1.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint_v1.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint_v1.sh"]
```

entrypoint_v1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir "anyfolder"
cp index.php cron.php
```

If I comment `ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint_v1.sh"]` working correctly but I want to execute some command.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's failing to keep running is because, as written, your entrypoint exits and the `docker run` therefore concludes.  The fact that `index.php` doesn't exist in the container doesn't help things, but since you're not running `bash` with `-e`, that error doesn't actually kill the container; the container ends when `entrypoint_v1.sh` exits at the end of the script directly thereafter.

But if you're copying files, that sounds like something like you could do in the Dockerfile yourself.  But it's not clear exactly what you're hoping to accomplish here, since you're thinking about adding PHP files to a MyQL database container.

If you want to run something at container startup time and *then start mysql*, you'll have to look to see what the upstream [`mysql:5.6` image's Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.6/Dockerfile) does when it starts.  Looking at that file, you might get what you want by adding this to your entrypoint:

```
exec /entrypoint.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your entrypoint_v1.sh script expects "index.php" to be inside the container, but you have not added it in Dockerfile. So it won't be able to find that file...

Comment: true, but that's not why it can't stay running.